# How to find if item in one Observable Collection?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I would like to request you to help me with this problem. I have an Observable Collection that stores favourites and I load items to another Observable Collection, so, what I want is for the new items which have unique IDs to be checked against Favourites Observable Collection in an efficient way as I feel what I am doing is not good enough.

What I am currently doing is as follows:

```
         foreach (var item in AllItems)
        {
            if (Watchlist.Fav.Count != 0)
            {
                if (Watchlist.Fav.Any(s => s.Id == item.Id)))
                {
                    Watchlist.Fav.Remove(Watchlist.Fav.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == item.Id));
                    Watchlist.Fav.Add(item);
                    item.IsFavorite = true;
                    ItmesCollection.Add(item);
                }
            }
       }
```

Could someone please help me make this better?

Cheers guys!

Comment: isn't `Remove` and `Add` operating same object? i think no need remove and add again. just update the properties needed.

Comment: you can use `Contains` to check if the object exists in the collection, but this only works if it is the same instance of the same object.  Otherwise what you are doing is fine.  Although as @LeiYang points out, Removing and then Adding the object again seems like wasted code, unless you have a specific reason for doing it.

Comment: Thanks LeiYang and Jason for pointing that out. I actually didn't know that I had a redundant code. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Since OP is asking a better syntax of current working code. Here is a try:

```cs
        foreach (var item in AllItems)
        {
            // no need check Watchlist.Fav.Count, because .Any duplicates
            // store matchingFav in variable so no need query twice
            var matchingFav = Watchlist.Fav.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == item.Id)));
            if (matchingFav != null)
            {
                matchingFav.IsFavorite = true;
                // where is ItemsCollection from? background not clear, so no change
                ItemsCollection.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

If the last statement is not relavant, syntax can be even shorter:

```cs
        var ids = new HashSet<int>(AllItems.Select(x => x.Id));
        foreach (var matchingFav in Watchlist.Fav
                                      .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)))
        {
            matchingFav.IsFavorite = true;
        }
```